# Selenium sometimes throws TimeoutException with presence_of_element_located()

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, python-3.6, webdriverwait

I'm using Selenium in Python 3.6 and it works fine, but not always.
I have this code:

```
 try:

    table = wait.until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((
            By.XPATH,
            "/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/"
            "tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[2]"
        ))
    )
except TimeoutException:
    driver.quit()
    return {
        "statusCode": 500,
        "body": json.dumps({"error": "WebPage dont load"}),
        "headers": {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }
    }
```

And this works, but sometimes there is a timeout exception, and I need this working 100% of the time. I already tried using `time.sleep(5)` , `presence_of_all_elements_located` , `visibility_of_element_located`, function to wait the webpage to load, but the problem is not fixed.

Also I have:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(20)
```

and

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
```

to make waits implicit and explicit.

Comment: Don't mix explicit and implicit waits.  That could be your problem right there. Also, you're path-based XPATH is brittle... try to find a better way to get the element you are looking for.  (The path may change during a DOM update...)

Comment: Thanks you for your comment, I will try using only explicit waits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure that the issue is not a bug, maybe the element is not always present on the page. If it is a bug, discuss it with developers.

If it is not a bug, use relative XPath instead of absolute, as absolute XPaths are very fragile. Or even better, use a unique ID or class.
You can find more info about XPath [here](https://www.swtestacademy.com/xpath-selenium/).

Comment: I think the problem is in the page actually, I'm already using only explicit waits and change the xpath for relative paths and the problem stil there.

Answer (score 0):

### presence_of_element_located()

[`presence_of_element_located()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.presence_of_element_located) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page. This does not necessarily mean that the element is visible. Hence it may not suffice to your needs.

---

### visibility_of_element_located()

[`visibility_of_element_located()`](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) is the expectation for checking that an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible. Visibility means that the element is not only displayed but also has a height and width that is greater than 0.

---

### This usecase

So ideally you need to replace `presence_of_element_located()` with **`visibility_of_element_located()`** and your effective code block will be:

```
try:

   table = wait.until(
       EC.visibility_of_element_located((
           By.XPATH,
           "/html/body/div/div[2]/div[1]/table/tbody/"
           "tr[2]/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table[2]"
       ))
   )
```

---

### Additional Consideration

Instead of using an *absolute* xpath you would be better with a *relative* xpath.

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [Selenium - wait until element is present, visible and interactable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336))
- [How to sleep webdriver in python for milliseconds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451)
- [WebDriverWait not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808)